# pass variable between function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function deletePlaylist(songid) { 
    var currentModal = $(this);
    currentModal.find('.btn-ok').click(function(songid) {
        console.log(songid);
    });
}
```

I need songid to pass from the upper function to the function below it.

Is there anywhere I can 'park' this variable to then pass it in?

Thanks.

Comment: You can access it from within the function, but not like this, this will get you the event object from the click listener with `songid` as it's name

Comment: "The function below it"... the function below it in the heirarchy? In the file?

Comment: if the function is defined within the click event, then if you remove songid from its arguments you will have access to the upper scoped variable.

Comment: Just remove it from the inner function and you can use it. Right now the second `songid` is shadowing the first one.

Comment: the function below it = row 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Scope is a set of rules for looking up variables by their identifier
>   name. There's usually more than one Scope to consider, however.
>
> Just as a block or function is nested inside another block or
>   function, scopes are nested inside other scopes. So, if a variable
>   cannot be found in the immediate scope, Engine consults the next outer
>   containing scope, continuing until found or until the outermost (aka,
>   global) scope has been reached.

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch1.md#nested-scope

This means, you can access outer scope from your function, you just don't have to "shadow" variable you need to access. Remove `songid` argument from inner function and you will be able to access `songid` from the outer scope.
You can read more about shadowing here:
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md#setting--shadowing-properties

Answer (score 0):

The `songid` parameter in your click event handler is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#JavaScript) the `songid` parameter to the `deletePlaylist` function. Moreover, the click event handler expects an event object, not a song ID. Remove the `songid` argument from the click handler:

```
function deletePlaylist(songid) { 
    var currentModal = $(this);
    currentModal.find('.btn-ok').click(function() {
        console.log(songid);
    });
}
```